# Export .obj file with png texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, file-format, obj

I'm playing around with [Google's new Augmented Reality SDK](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/getting-started). 
Their [example project](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk) contains an `.obj` file but its' textures are not in a `.mtl` file, put a `.png` file; no `.mlt` file at all (example for an Android robot model below).

From a little research I take this is not the 'standard' procedure of exporting a model / it's texture in the `.obj` format from Blender (or similar programs).

Is there a way to still achieve this (textures in `.png` instead of `.mtl`) with Blender?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: The way Google did it appears to be a very simplistic way and I wasn't able to find any converter to do this. However, I found updated code to handle MTL files instead of trying to find this magical diffuse image converter. See the second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985643/obj-file-for-arcode-app-development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .mtl file is only a material definition file which contains references to textures.

if you want to export obj with .mtl and textures you need to make sure you follow these steps:

In your OBJ export menu:

- Make sure material export is ticked

[image: enable material export]

- Set the path mode on COPY

[image: path mode]

You will see that in your target folder you now have

- An obj file which contains your mesh information
- An mtl file which contains material definition
- All tetxure files referenced in the .mtl

Comment: It does not create a png file for the texture. Any solution ?

Comment: @Regis_AG did you manage to create .png texture file?

Answer (score 1):

To export an image texture at Blender do the following:

Select your object and enter in edit mode. Select all vertices/faces (press 'a'). Then start the UV Mapping, press 'u'. And Select one of the options of the UVMapping. You must test the best option for you model.

[image]

Then go to the UV/Image Editor:

[image]

Export UV Layout at the menu, and save your image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way, but off topic way, to get a png out of an mtl, is to make a Roblox account, download Roblox studio.

Make a new baseplate game, insert a meshpart and then go to *View -> Properties* and then enable properties tab, then look at the properties tab of the meshpart and then you should see a folder button on the side of the mesh section, and then click it, insert your mesh, and under the mesh id, you should see a texture.

Copy the id, only the numbers, then type in exactly this and replace `(insert id here)` with your id: `roblox.com/library/(insert id here)/name` and then it should redirect you to a link with the image.

If it has an image of a piece of paper and an hourglass, you need to wait for it to be an approved image.

Answer (score 0):

ensure your object has uv's and then bake out the map you want to a texture using the bake section in the render settings.

Comment: What's the reason for baking in this case?