# How do I change the MTL File to an actual image?

Tags: texturing, materials

When exporting my Model and importing it into another engine, It require an Image file as the texture instead of a MTL file, so I was just wondering how I would accomplish changing the mtl to and image file

Comment: Investigate Baking with Blender. Baking records all the textures(plus lighting etc) as single result as if it had been rendered from multiple angles.What engine are you importing into?

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same :-)

Answer (score 1):

A MTL file is just a material definition. It doesn't contain image data. See here for further (all) details about the MTL file format: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/

If you're using OBJ files, you need three things:

- the model data as OBJ, contains vertices, faces, smoothing groups and texture coordinates, etc.
- the texture(s) (any image format, e.g. PNG)
- the material library file (which is referenced in your OBJ file)

See also:

- [the blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/io_obj.html) about the OBJ file format
- [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90301/export-obj-file-with-png-texture) question for OBJ exporting options in Blender