# Can someone please help me get at the textures of this Sketchfab model?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, vertex-colors, obj

For reference, the model is here: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/otto-the-autopilot-7db2b78e311a44ac9b84b1bb6f768413. It's a very nice free model of a classic movie "character", the likes of which are not available anywhere else online that I can see.

I can import the glTF file into Blender and it looks good. I can save as a .blend file and then open that, and it is the same, so the textures must be in that somewhere. But when I export to .obj to use with another 3D program, there are no textures. There is an .mtl file, but it doesn't reference anything. No folder with any image files in it either.

I've searched this site for a solution and nothing I've come across seems to work. Of course, I am a total Blender newb so I may not be understanding some of this stuff properly. For example here: [Export .obj file with png texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90301/export-obj-file-with-png-texture) ..."Select all vertices/faces (press 'a'). Then start the UV Mapping, press 'u'." When I press 'u' nothing happens.

Somewhere else there was the advice to simply go to UV edit, select the texture and "save as". But there are no textures when I go to UV edit.

Like I said, I am very new to Blender, can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

There are no textures.  As is often the case, Sketchfab models in gltf format consist of a number of objects all parented to an empty. In this case there a dozen, named 'Object_2' through 'Object_13'.  They all share this material, called "Scene_-_Root":

[image: Material for Objects]

That is, they're all using [*Vertex Paint*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/vertex_paint/index.html) to set a solid color for that piece of Otto.